# Angular 'this' not working inside directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code. Why doesn't the `vm.name` work? Why is the `this` inside the controller not being detected? Haven't I defined a closed `scope` for the directive?

What  am I doing wrong?

```
var mod = angular.module('myApp', []);

mod.directive('myObj', myObject);

function myObject(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'my-obj.html',
      scope: {},
      controller: myController
  };

  function myController(){
    var vm = this;

    vm.name="vfdfbdn";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `this` in controller inside directive you need to use `controllerAs: 'ctrl'` but then in template you will need to prefix all name with `{{ctrl.name}}` or you can use $scope like:

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.name="vfdfbdn";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myObject(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>{{c.name}}</div>',
      scope: {},
      controller: myController,
      controllerAs: 'c'
  };

  function myController(){
    var vm = this;

    vm.name="vfdfbdn";
  }
};
```

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers) to understand the things

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myObject() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-obj.html',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: true,
        controller: myController
    };
}


myController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function myController($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.name="vfdfbdn";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Angular how you are going to reference the `this` from the controller in the view.

```
function myObject(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'my-obj.html',
      scope: {},
      controller: myController,
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  };
}
```

Now you can reference everything that you assigned to `this`, that you named `vm` in your controller with `ctrl`.

I used *ctrl* to show that there is no correlation between the name you use to refere to it in the view, setted with `controllerAs` and the name you give to `this` inside the controller function. It is a normal to reference different controllers with different *controllerAs* references so you can now which controller they refer to in the view.